# Datatable jumps to top of page anytime it re-calculates

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have an R Shiny app that renders a datatable (using the DT package) that has a lot of rows and requires scrolling down the page to see them. Anytime the table re-calculates, it jumps the vertical scroll-bar on the page back to the top. I can't figure out how to prevent that from happening. Hoping to get suggestions. Here's a minimal working example that illustrates the problem:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)


ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    DTOutput("tab")
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  # auto-refresh every 2 seconds
  autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(2000, session)
  
  dd <- reactive({
    
    autoInvalidate()
    
    # generate table with a bunch of random numbers
    data.frame(x = rnorm(10000))
  })
  
  output$tab <- renderDT({
    datatable(dd(),
              options = list(pageLength = 500))
  })
  
  
  
  
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: When use `isolate(dd())` it freezes the data and stops re-generating data every 2 seconds.  I want it to keep re-generating the data every couple seconds, but I don't want it to jump to the top when I do it.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dataTableProxy` along with `replaceData` to avoid re-rendering the whole widget every time the data changes - this by the way is also faster:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    DTOutput("tab")
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  dd <- reactive({
    invalidateLater(2000)
    data.frame(x = rnorm(10000))
  })
  
  output$tab <- renderDT({
    # render once on startup
    datatable(isolate(dd()),
              options = list(pageLength = 500))
  })
  
  tabProxy <- dataTableProxy("tab")
  
  observe({
    DT::replaceData(tabProxy, dd())
  })
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```